# Domain search entries in resolv.conf and ifcfg-ens33 files

Tags: domain, centos-7, resolv.conf

In CentOS, when we modify `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33` file for multiple domain search entries, should we also manually change `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

There are **search** entries in `resolv.conf` and entries as **DOMAIN=** in `ifcfg-ens33`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the NetworkManager service, should update the information. There should be no need to manually update the /etc/resolv.conf file.